# Container and sidebar at right side

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve something, I want a main container and a sidebar at the rightside. which should deal with mobile layout as well, I was unable to find such thing or make it. The blue print is given in the image below. Thanks
[BluePtint of what im trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZw5a.png)

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)

Comment: What you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can create this layout using div's with different ids or classes- your main body(red) could go in a div with class "#mainbody" and your sidebar(blue) would go in another div with class "#sidebar", then you can specify the dimensions in CSS.

Have you checked out a CSS framework like Bootstrap? Bootstrap makes it super easy to specify column widths with their grid system, so instead of having to state px or % width in CSS, you can add the class "col-md-3" to a column for a width of "3". Their system is based on units of 12, where 12 would be a full bar, 6 would be half etc: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: So you mean I have to make 2 divs and nest two divs in a single div :/